# install laserjet 2200 printer from the command line using lpadmin

Tags: drivers, hp-printer

I am using arch linux kernel 5.7.2-arch1-1.
All software is up to date.

I am attempting to set-up a Laserjet 2200 printer from the command line using the utility `lpadmin`.

While I am able to use the `system-config-printer` GUI utility to set up the printer so it works, I prefer to be able to do this from the command line as it is much more portable. When I set-up using the GUI method the working printer gives some information about the working driver. The `make and model` field is filled as `HP LaserJet 2200 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.3.3`.

Being able to replicate this set-up on the command line would be ideal.
I've had a brief look at the Gutenprint web site and the pdf document they have and there apprears to have no set-up information in there, that I can see.

The below printer set-up command is accepted by the terminal, but the newly set-up printer accepts the print job but fails to print:

```
lpadmin -p "hp_laserjet_2200" -d "hp_laserjet_2200" -o printer-is-shared=false -e -i ~/script_PRINTER_CUPS_config_file/hp-laserjet-2200.ppd -v socket://192.168.1.240:9100
```

I think this command should work and that the problem is the `.ppd` file, though I am sure that I used this same `.ppd` file many years ago for a same model printer.

What is the GUI app accessing that I can't see?

Do I need more than a once upon a time working ppd file?

Where can I get a newer ppd file (a search revealed nothing)?

What is the method to set-up this laserjet printer from the command line?

I feel certian this is simply a driver problem. I have done much googling but the answer is not so far clear. I have installed `hplip` which I think has a gui, but as I say I want to do this entireley on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what worked for me, in a step by step breakdown.

There's probarly other simpler ways to get your printer set-up as a one liner in linux.

1. Install gutenprint and hplib driver softwares if not already installed. Here is the code I used.

`package_list=( gutenprint hplip )
for i in "${package_list[@]}"
do
if [ "$(echo $sudo_password | sudo -S pacman -Qi | grep -m 1 -oE $i)" = "$i" ]; then
echo "$i is already installed, no need to do anything";
else
echo $sudo password | sudo -S pacman -S $i --noconfirm --needed
fi
done`

2. Run the `lpinfo` command to search for the drivers on your system.
   In my case I have an HP LaserJet 2200 printer, so I greped for it as follows

   `lpinfo -m | grep 2200 | grep LaserJet`

You can use your printer make and model with this command, it worked for me

lpinfo --make-and-model "HP LaserJet 2200" -m

The output will be something like this
gutenprint.5.3://hp-lj_2200/expert HP LaserJet 2200 - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.3.3
lsb/usr/HP/hp-laserjet_2200-ps.ppd.gz HP LaserJet 2200 Postscript
lsb/usr/HP/hp-laserjet_2200_series-ps.ppd.gz HP LaserJet 2200 Postscript
drv:///hp/hpcups.drv/hp-laserjet_2200_series.ppd HP LaserJet 2200 Series, hpcups 3.20.5
lsb/usr/HP/hp-laserjet_2200_series.ppd.gz HP LaserJet 2200 Series, hpcups 3.20.5
everywhere IPP Everywhere

3. Select an appropriate drv line. I selected this one

   drv:///hp/hpcups.drv/hp-laserjet_2200_series.ppd
4. Then use that in the below printer setup line

   lpadmin -p "HP_LaserJet_2200_LOCAL" 
   -D "HP_LaserJet_2200_LOCAL" 
   -L "Corridor" 
   -o printer-is-shared=false 
   -E 
   -m drv:///hp/hpcups.drv/hp-laserjet_2200_series.ppd 
   -v socket://192.168.1.240:9100

Here is what each flag does, terms definitions:

- -p = printer name
- -D = printer description
- -L = printer location
- -o printer-is-shared=false. This stops other people using the printer via your computer.
- -E = Enable printer
- -m = driver / ppd location
- -v = uri-socket

5. Set your printer as default if you have a few and wish to do so

   lpadmin -d HP_LaserJet_2200_LOCAL